# How to convert a scanned PDF to searchable PDF in C#?

Tags: pdf-generation

I want to give a input as a scanned PDF then my expected output is searchable PDF. Want to copy the text from the scanned PDF. Please provide the code with libraries in C#.

Actually I don't want to extract text from PDF. I want to copy the text from PDF and paste to textbox.

Comment: Most scanned PDF's do not allow you to copy and paste.

Comment: Most likely your "scanned pdf" does only contain the scanned images (i.e. bitmaps) but no explicit textual information. Thus, there is no text to copy or extract. You need to apply ocr (optical character recognition) to the pdf first.

Comment: This does sound like an OCR question, but otherwise it is too broad. Voting to close. Also OP, please refrain from adding "urgent" to your questions - this is not a good way to address volunteers.